# Updating all the documents of MongoDB collection array using mongo Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to achieve below update functionality via Java code

```
db.getCollection("test_rohit").update(
  {},
  {
    $push: {
      x_axis: {
         $each: [ ],
         $slice: -1
      }
    }
  },
  { multi: true } 
)
```

---

-

i have written below code to solve it

```
DBObject eachObject =new BasicDBObject();
eachObject.put("$each", new String[0]);
eachObject.put("$slice", -1);
BasicDBObject pushDbObject =new BasicDBObject();
pushDbObject.append("x_axis", eachObject);
Bson modifiedObject =set("$push", pushDbObject);
Bson filter=new BasicDBObject("", "");
long result = collection.updateMany(filter, modifiedObject ).getModifiedCount();
```

But its not working because i guess the filter object is not matching to {} (which generally means for all the documents) , so how can i create a filter object for {}.

---

sample document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8718b9b5fe262104408374"),
    "axis" : "x",
    "message_time" : ISODate("2019-03-11T08:04:41.000Z"),
    "x_axis" : [ 
        0.9766, 
        1.9531, 
        2.9297, 
        3.9063, 
        4.8828, 
        5.8594, 
        6.8359, 
        7.8125, 
        8.7891,
    ],
    "etl_date_time" : ISODate("2019-03-12T02:26:01.510Z")
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample document.

Comment: @ Wernfried Domscheit updated the question with sample document. i am trying to preserve last data of each x axis array in all the documents. since the size of collection is  more (i.e. 5 million docs) so can't do find and then by iterating  pass each id to the update query for filtering